# sending requests to my own API to make changes to DB which is not being updated. I would like the DB to be updated

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

Im having trouble understanding how to make request to an API that was set up with express to do CRUD methods. in the below code `.get(/bears)` renders a form and in the `app.post('/bears')` i'm using the nPmodule 'request' to send the request to the api/bears router by doing this i expect name attr of the text box which is the same field on the db to be added to the db (`bear.save(function(err){` )It doesn't that is the problem.

someone please show me how to make calls from a route(page) to the api so the api could update the db from the form in the html from the view.

I think Angular has services for this but I want to see how to do this with express. Is there away to do it with out the npm request?

**[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zhk152pf/)** with more of the code

```
app.get('/bears', function(req, res){
   res.render('index', {message : "You are rendered!"});     
})
app.post('/bears', function(req, res){
// request.post('http://localhost:8080/api/bears',function(error, response, body){
//  if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
//      var info = JSON.parse(body)
//      res.send(info);
//  }else{
//      res.send(error);
//  }
// })
   request.post('http://localhost:8080/api/bears', function(error, response, body){
      console.log(body);
      console.log(response)
   })


})

router.route('/bears')
.post(function(req, res){
    var bear = new Bear();
    bear.name = req.body.name;

    bear.save(function(err){
        if(err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json({message : 'Bear created!'});
    })
})
.get(function(req, res){

    Bear.find(function(err, bears){
        if(err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json(bears);
        console.log(bears[0].id)
    })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work   . I didn't know I could put `req.body.name` as a 'value'

[request form documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#forms)

```
 app.post('/bears', function(req, res){
// request.post('http://localhost:8080/api/bears',function(error, response, body){
//  if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
//      var info = JSON.parse(body)
//      res.send(info);
//  }else{
//      res.send(error);
//  }
// })
request.post({url : 'http://localhost:8080/api/bears', form : {name : req.body.name }}, function(err, httpResponse, body){
    res.redirect("/alpha");
})


})
app.get('/alpha', function(req, res){
res.send('It was updated');
})
```